# Dropping a token in NSTokenField

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nstokenfield

I am implementing an app where rows from an `NSTableView` can be dragged and dropped into an `NSTokenField`, but I am struggling to implement the drop-side of the interaction. I have subclassed `NSTokenField` (as shown below in the debugging code below). But I am only seeing calls to `draggingEntered:` and `updateDraggingItemsForDrag:` method. Even though I return a valid `NSDragOperation` (`Copy`), none of the other methods in `NSDraggingDestination` are called. The cursor briefly flashes to the copy icon when moving over the token field, but then returns to the normal cursor.

I tried implementing all the methods associated with `NSDraggingDestination` for debugging purposes, shown in the code below. Is there another class or part of the `NSTokenField` that is handling the drop? Is it possible to override that?

I have confirmed that the pasteboard does have data with the valid pasteboard type.

```
let kPasteboardType = "SamplePasteboardType"

class MyTokenField : NSTokenField
{
    override func draggingEntered(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        // entered
        NSLog("ENTERED")

        // must come from same window
        guard self.window == sender.draggingDestinationWindow() else {
            return super.draggingEntered(sender)
        }


        // has valid pasteboard data?
        let pb = sender.draggingPasteboard()
        if let _ = pb.dataForType(kPasteboardType) {
            NSLog("MATCHED")
            return NSDragOperation.Copy
        }

        return super.draggingEntered(sender)
    }

    override func draggingUpdated(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        NSLog("UPDATED")

        // must come from same window
        guard self.window == sender.draggingDestinationWindow() else {
            return super.draggingUpdated(sender)
        }

        // has valid pasteboard data?
        let pb = sender.draggingPasteboard()
        if let _ = pb.dataForType(kPasteboardType) {
            return NSDragOperation.Copy
        }

        return super.draggingUpdated(sender)
    }

    override func draggingExited(sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        NSLog("EXITED")

        super.draggingExited(sender)
    }

    override func prepareForDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        NSLog("PREPARE")

        return super.prepareForDragOperation(sender)
    }

    override func performDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        NSLog("PERFORM")

        return super.performDragOperation(sender)
    }

    override func concludeDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        NSLog("CONCLUDE")

        super.concludeDragOperation(sender)
    }

    override func draggingEnded(sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        NSLog("ENDED")

        super.draggingEnded(sender)
    }

    override func updateDraggingItemsForDrag(sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        // super.updateDraggingItemsForDrag(sender)
        guard let drag = sender else {
            return
        }

        let classes: [AnyClass] = [NSPasteboardItem.self]
        let options: [String: AnyObject] = [NSPasteboardURLReadingContentsConformToTypesKey: [kPasteboardType]]

        drag.enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions(NSDraggingItemEnumerationOptions.ClearNonenumeratedImages, forView: self, classes: classes, searchOptions: options) {
            (item, idx, stop) in
            NSLog("\(item)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [This makes is sound like all you need is the two pasteboard methods in `NSTokenFieldDelegate`](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/05/tokenize-this/).  `<NSDraggingDestination>` appears to have to do with manipulating the image being dragged as it enters a view... +1 nonetheless.  Good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @stevesliva, I was able to solve the problem. There are some key caveats that I discovered (they may be partly due to my ignorance of pasteboard and drag/drop interactions).

1. Subclassing the `NSTokenField` class is not necessary.
2. I had to implement the delegate function `tokenField(tokenField: NSTokenField, readFromPasteboard pboard: NSPasteboard) -> [AnyObject]?` for the token field.
3. I had to change start of the drag to store a string value to the pasteboard. It seems like if the pasteboard does not have a string value, then the above delegate function is never called.